# ToggleButton makes mediaplayer play twice at once

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-button

I have a mediaplayer that plays music in the activity below. The thing is, the music transfers to all other activities and thats fine. But when I start the music, go to another activity and then come back to the activity below, the togglebutton has changed from on to off. Therefore, if I click on the togglebutton, the music starts again even though the music is still playing so now the music is playing twice at once! How do I make the togglebutton know that the music is playing so when I come back to the activity, the togglebutton is "on" from the beginning? It's "off" by default.

```
public class SpelaActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spela);

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.ljudfil);

    ToggleButton musikknapp = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglemusik);
    musikknapp.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
});
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the mediaplayer to stop upon back button click:

```
final ToggleButton togglemusik = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglemusik);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ljudfil);
    togglemusik.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (togglemusik.isChecked()) {
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.pause();
            }   
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mp !=null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need save the ToggleButton State.
Try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private static Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState", toggleButton.isChecked());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        toggleButton.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false));
    }
```

Comment: That sets the togglebutton to "on" when I come back to the activity after switching to another activity but it also makes the music start without me clicking the togglebutton!? So I'm still unable to control the music to be either "on" or "off"? Or am I supposed to put this code in the main activity?

Comment: Verify mediaplayer is playing: mp.isPlaying()

Comment: How do you mean? I tried to change isChecked to mediaPlayer.isPlaying() in the if else statement but that didn't do it. As before, the togglebutton does what it's supposed to while I'm in that specific activity. As soon as I leave it and come back, that when the trouble starts happening. Is there perhaps some way to isolate the mediaplayer to just play music in that activity?

Answer (score 0):

add these condition  `if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())`

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } else {
                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean `if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){`? I tried both of your alternative solutions but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: check these link there is code of media player : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/